# Taxicab algorithm using priority queue

Tags: algorithm, priority-queue

Taxicab number is a number that can be expressed as the sum of two cubes, expressed in two different ways where integers `a, b, c, d` are not equal. The following code uses priority queues to generate such numbers.

```
for i = 1..n
   pq.insert( Vector(i^3+i^3,i,i) )

  prev = Vector(0, 0, 0)
  while not pq.empty()
     curr = pq.deleteMin()
     if prev[0] == curr[0]
        print curr[0] is a Taxicab number that can be expressed as
        prev[1]^3 + prev[2]^3 and curr[1]^3 + curr[2]^3
     prev = curr
     if curr[2] < N
        j = curr[2] + 1
        pq.insert( Vector(curr[1]^3+ j^3, curr[1], j) )
```

One of such numbers is: `1729 = 12^3 + 1^3 = 10^3 + 9^3`.
How is it possible to have `prev = [1729, 12, 1]` and `current = [1729, 10, 9]` if with each iteration of the while loop, the only (top ie. min) element in the priority queue is deleted and prev is equal to the number from iteration before, so for this example it would be `[1512, 10, 8]` (since while loop only modifies the 1st and 3rd element).

Comment: What is your question or problem? Please make it clear.

Comment: I am trying to understand how this algorithm returns what it is asked to compute.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that when you insert an element into a priority queue, it naturally falls to the level specified by its first element.  Thus you insert elements in whatever order you think of them, you pull them out ordered by the sum.  As long as the sum of the things you then insert is larger than what you pulled out, you will get everything out in the right order even though you didn't start with everything in it.